# Finding minimun and maximum using recursion in C program

Tags: c, function, recursion

I need your help please.

I need to do a recursive function that finds the minimum and the maximum of any array it receives.

I need to implement function `void minMax(int arr[], int left, int right, int min_max[])`, but I don't know how to start, I would like if you'll give me some ideas.

This is an e.x to how the output supposed to show:
`min_max[1]=100 ו min_max[0]=(-4)`

On this detail:
`left = 2 , right = 5, arr = [3,−1,3,100,2,−4,3]`, assumption : left <= right.

Thank you all.

Comment: If you are allowed to sort the array this is easy (recursive sorting algorithms exist)

Comment: put some effort before asking

Answer (score 2):

i think what you are looking for is the *Tournament Method* :

> Divide the array into two parts and compare the maximums and minimums of the two parts to get the maximum and the minimum of the whole array

(this is similar to binary search)

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct pair 
{
int min;
int max;
}; 

struct pair getMinMax(int arr[], int low, int high)
  {
    struct pair minmax, mml, mmr;    
    int mid;

    // If there is only one element 
    if (low == high)
      {
          minmax.max = arr[low];
          minmax.min = arr[low];     
          return minmax;
      } 

     /* If there are two elements */
    if (high == low + 1)
      {  
         if (arr[low] > arr[high]) 
      {
            minmax.max = arr[low];
            minmax.min = arr[high];
      } 
    else
      {
            minmax.max = arr[high];
            minmax.min = arr[low];
      } 
    return minmax;
   }

   /* If there are more than 2 elements */
   mid = (low + high)/2; 
   mml = getMinMax(arr, low, mid);
   mmr = getMinMax(arr, mid+1, high); 

  /* compare minimums of two parts*/
   if (mml.min < mmr.min)
        minmax.min = mml.min;
   else
        minmax.min = mmr.min;    

  /* compare maximums of two parts*/
  if (mml.max > mmr.max)
       minmax.max = mml.max;
  else
       minmax.max = mmr.max;     

  return minmax;
 }

/* Driver program to test above function */
int main()
{
int arr[] = {1000, 11, 445, 1, 330, 3000};
int arr_size = 6;
struct pair minmax = getMinMax(arr, 0, arr_size-1);
printf("nMinimum element is %d", minmax.min);
printf("nMaximum element is %d", minmax.max);
getchar();
}
```

source : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-and-minimum-in-an-array/ (Method 2)

Comment: Minor: Given "assumption : left <= right.", `mid = (low + high)/2;` may overflow, where `mid = low + (high - low)/2;` does not.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I guess you right about the similarity to binary search, but the solution supposed to be simple in recursion. In addition, i need to use the function signature, in all the parameters that mentioned above.

Comment: @user14674651 The difference from your signature is only different naming (`left` -> `low`, etc.) and the returned `pair struct` instead of  `max_max` passed as pointer. It should be easy to refactor it properly...

Comment: @Bob__ but the solution need to be simply then that (maybe 7 lines of code), and i can't figure out how. you have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

First of all this question has a terrible redaction. In order to get better answers you should work more on your questions otherwise it makes it harder for the other people to help you and also feels like you haven't done enough prior research.

About the content of your question I would solve this with pseudocode first (As with any other "hard" problem). I supose this is homework because you already have the function signature.

The **left** and **right** parameters aren't needed or I am not understanding what they are used for.

The pseudocode function could look like this:

```
function minMax(arr, mixMax)
  if arr is empty
    return
  
  elem = extract last elem from arr

  if mixMax[0] is empty or elem > mixMax[0]
    mixMax[0] = elem

  if mixMax[1] is empty or elem < mixMax[1] 
    mixMax[1] = elem

  minMax(arr, minMax)
```

Comment: Note that you could use those `left` and `right` parameters to specify smaller and smaller subsets. Beeing this a question about `c`, what do you mean with "if mixMax[0] is empty" and could you please explain how the recursion is implemented in this pseudo code?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know C that said the minMax array could be initialized with [Null, Null] values which are replaced in the first recursion, that's what I meant with "empty".

The recursion works because you extract one element for recursion from the array, that way the array size decreases each time until is empty, where the base condition is met. (arr is empty). Note that the minMax(arr, minMax) function call is inside the function scope.

Comment: Ok, but please note that `int` type doesn't have a Null state, an `int` variable *always* has a value. It may be 0, INT_MAX (the maximum integer value), 42 or it may be indeterminate (whatever there was in memory) if it's uninitialized. Also, to implement the concept of "the array size decreases each time" you should pass the extents too (`int arr[]` is just a pointer to the first element, the notion of the size is lost, but with `left` and `right` the function may know the first and last index of the subarray).

Comment: @Bob__  I have must used all the parameters in the function signature, left and right parameters are an indexs of the array.

Comment: @Bob__ Understood, as I said I don't know C, so I can't foresee it's technical constraints. In JS or Python you can seamlessly fill an array with Null values and also increase or decrease it's size over time. To avoid the Null problem you could initialiaze the minMax array with INT_MAX and INT_MIN. Also you could get rid of the `right` parameter and use only the `left` one to move the index but It's kind of the same as using both parameter and slicing the array, also there are probably performance reasons on using slices of the array,

Comment: Yes, at least one of those parameters is redundant, even in c, but they seem to be part of the constraints of OP's assignment (which is horrible IMHO, I personally hate those kind of preposterous examples of recursion, but that's immaterial).